# Simple checkbox logic

Tags: android, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

The problem that was given to me in our class is that you have the option to check 4 Checkboxes that are labeled (A, B, C, D). Each checkbox has a value of 10. If you check one, the number that will be shown in the EditText will be 10, if you check two it will be 20 and so on.

Can anyone show me hows the onClick class on this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use RadioButton instead of Checkbox if you want to show only one vale at a time in the EditText.

Comment: Keep a count. Increment the counter when checkbox is checked in the listener and vice versa. Update the edit text based on the current count *10.

Answer (score 0):

Create four checkboxes with different Ids, say CB_One,CB_Two,CB_Three,CB_Four with Ids cb_one,cb_two,cb_three,cb_four. Put onCheckedChangedListener for all and then on checkChenged pass values to the editText as 10,20,30 40.

```
CB_One.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
               editText.setText("10");
        } else{
              editText.setText("");
        }
   }
 }

);

CB_Two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
               editText.setText("20");
        } else{
              editText.setText("");
        }
   }
 }

);

CB_Three.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
               editText.setText("30");
        } else{
              editText.setText("");
        }
   }
 }

);

CB_Four.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
               editText.setText("40");
        } else{
              editText.setText("");
        }
   }
 }

);
```

Comment: Keep a counter and have a common listener to reduce code thus making it more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

user the OnCheckChangeListener of checkbox like this

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
               // increment your counter by 10
        } else{
              // Decrement your counter by 10
        }
   }
 }

);
```